# Runtime stack overflow from lodash.clonedeep, using mongoose to establish a sessionMongoStore connection

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, lodash, stack-overflow

Update: This is likely a deeper problem and have nothing to do with, e.g., importing of lodash.

It appears that, in this code that I've inherited, cloneDeep is used in several places and that it might be an actual problem with some circularity in what's being cloned. If so, I'll close this issue and (likely) push out some others.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| nodeJS | v14.20.0 |
| typescript | v4.6.4 |
| mongodb | v4.9.1 |
| mongoose | v6.6.1 |
| connect-mongodb-session | v3.1.1 |
| lodash | v4.17.21 |

After upgrading an application across multiple levels, the one **show-stopper** is configuring and connecting to mongo, via mongoose, switching from connect-mongo to connect-mongodb-session. The build completed without error, but running the app results in:

```
/Users/.../node_modules/lodash.clonedeep/index.js:841 
function baseClone(value, isDeep, isFull, customizer, key, object, stack) {
                  ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded 
   at baseClone (/Users/.../node_modules/lodash.clonedeep/index.js:841:19)
   at /Users/.../node_modules/lodash.clonedeep/index.js:897:30
...
```

This happens with mongoose configuration:

```
import mongo from 'connect-mongodb-session';
import mongoose from './db'

const MongoStore = mongo(session);

...

const sessionMongoStore = new MongoStore({
      autoReconnect: true,
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
    });
    app.use(
      session({
        secret: 'Pnv68aFuBy',
        store: sessionMongoStore,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
      })
    );
```

The file db.ts, which extends mongoose to provide/define a properly configured mongoose connection, contains:

```
import assert from 'assert';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import appEnv from './appenv';
import bluebird from 'bluebird';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

(mongoose as any).Promise = bluebird;
 
...

mongoose.connect( connectionString)
  .then( () => { /* resolves to undefined */})
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('MongoDB connection error: ' + err);
  });

export default mongoose;
```

This all worked at the following versions:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| nodeJS | v12.22.12 |
| typescript | v3.8.3 |
| mongodb | v3.3.13 |
| mongoose | v5.9.12 |
| connect-mongo | v3.1.2 |
| lodash | v4.17.13 |

I'm wondering whether the inclusion of the db.ts file is creating some kind of infinite recursion for lodash.

Answer (score 0):

Getting past the red herrings, the problem was not within user code but in one of the installed node modules - specifically, the (obsolete) use of `app.use(helmet.noCache());` which contained the errant use of `lodash.cloneDeep`.

A colleague had recommended replacing lodash.cloneDeep with [clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone). "...with the circular attribute set to true (then you can slowly set it to false in some places until it fails)". As none of the references failed, it was a simple matter of looking into the many node_moodules. The hint was the warning that `helmet.noCache()` had been deprecated.

Fixing this is simple. In the application code:

1. insert `import  noCache from 'nocache';`
2. replace `app.use(helmet.noCache());` with `app.use(noCache());`